# VB script for send mail

Tags: email, batch-file, vbscript

I dont have knowledge about vb scripting. so m asking here please help me... :)
we have one backup batch script which copy all data to another server using robo copy.
we schedule that script, but all the time we have to go that server and check manually that script run or not.
now we have write one vb script that will call that batch script and check that script run properly if script run properly then mail will come as backup completed else backup is not completed.
please if you have any idea about vb script please help me.

Comment: Here is a great link that gives lots of options: http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm

Comment: You can use `Blat.exe` who is a great command line tool to send E-mail

Answer (score 0):

You can use mailsend.exe , just have the exe placed in your scripts folder & append the below code to you RoboCopy script at the end. If you don't want to cc or bcc anyone just add +cc & +bcc

type logs.txt | mailsend.exe -smtp smtp_server_ip_or_FQDN -port 25 -d smtp.mail.com -t xyz@mail.com -f seding_from@mail.com -sub "Whatever Subject" -user mail_username@mail.com -pass mailpassword -auth -cc xyz@mail.com -bcc xyz@mail.com

Answer (score 0):

Here's a batch file that uses VBS to send an email.

Read the comments in the script to see how to test it.

```
:: email.bat :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
setlocal

:: use these settings to send from a gmail account
:: set port=465 and set SSL=True

:: use these settings for standard email SMTP port and no encryption
:: set port=25 and set SSL=False

:: Change these following items to use the same variables all the time
:: or use the command line to pass all the variables

set Port=25
set SSL=False
set From="myemail@myemailserver.com"
set To="recipient@server.com"
set Subject="Subject line"
set Body="Email Body in one line"
set SMTPServer="mailservername.myemailserver.com"
set User="username"
set Pass="password"
set fileattach="d:\myfolder\file.txt"


:: This section sets the command line arguments
:: use this format:  CALL email.bat "myname@gmail.com" "RecipientEmailAddress@server.com" "Subject line" "Email Body in one line" "smtp.gmail.com"  "myname@gmail.com" "password" "d:\folder\filename to attach.txt"


if "%~7" NEQ "" (
set From="%~1"
set To="%~2"
set Subject="%~3"
set Body="%~4"
set SMTPServer="%~5"
set User="%~6"
set Pass="%~7"
set fileattach="%~8"
)

set "vbsfile=%temp%\email-bat.vbs"
del "%vbsfile%" 2>nul
set cdoSchema=http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration
echo >>"%vbsfile%" Set objArgs       = WScript.Arguments
echo >>"%vbsfile%" Set objEmail      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.From     = %From%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.To       = %To%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Subject  = %Subject%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Textbody = %body%
if exist %fileattach% echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.AddAttachment %fileattach%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" with objEmail.Configuration.Fields
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendusing")        = 2 ' not local, smtp
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpserver")       = %SMTPServer%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpserverport")   = %port%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpauthenticate") = 1 ' cdobasic
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendusername")     = %user%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendpassword")     = %pass%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpusessl")       = %SSL%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 30
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Update
echo >>"%vbsfile%" end with
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Send

cscript.exe /nologo "%vbsfile%"
echo email sent (if variables were correct)
del "%vbsfile%" 2>nul
goto :EOF
```