# Text Emailing using VBscript

Tags: email, vbscript

I have tried the following code, No errors thrown. and no emails have been sent either.

```
Dim i, objEmail

' Use custom error handling
On Error Resume Next

Set objEmail = CreateObject( "CDO.Message" )

' Fill in the field values
With objEmail
    .From     = "xyz@abc.com"
    .To       = "pqr@abc.com"
    .Subject  = "Test"
    .TextBody = "Email from VB Script" 

If mySMTPPort = "" Then
        mySMTPPort = 25
    End If

With .Configuration.Fields
        .Item( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing"      ) = 2
        .Item( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver"     ) = "HostNameHere"
        .Item( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport" ) = 25
        .Update
    End With
    .Send
End With
' Return status message
If Err Then
    EMail = "ERROR " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
Else
    EMail = "Message sent ok"
End If

' Release the e-mail message object
Set objEmail = Nothing
```

When I execute this VBS file, It just does nothing at all. Please help me out. I have to send simple text emails from my domain to another domain. Or is there a work around for the task i want to perform?

Comment: Do you want a batch file to do it?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010079/vb-script-for-send-mail/23011839#23011839

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting an error when trying to send mail. However, you have error handling enabled (`On Error Resume Next`), but your error handler just puts the error information in a variable without actually doing anything with that variable. Adding a line that echoes the variable should provide you with more information about what's going on:

```vbs
If Err Then
    EMail = "ERROR " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
Else
    EMail = "Message sent ok"
End If
WScript.Echo EMail
```

should provide you with more information about what's going on.

**Edit:** Apparently you're getting a connection error. There are several possible causes for that. First check that your name resolution works correctly:

```
nslookup HostNameHere
```

If the name doesn't resolve either use the IP address in your script or get the name resolution fixed.

Next check if you can connect to port 25 on the remote host, both via name and IP address:

```
telnet HostNameHere 25
telnet a.b.c.d 25
```

If you get a result like this:

```
C:\>telnet HostNameHere 25
Connecting To HostNameHere...Could not open connection to the host, on port 25:
Connect failed
```

something is blocking your connection. Could be a network firewall, a host-based firewall on the remote host, or the service not listening on port 25 in the first place. Check with your network admins and/or the admin(s) of the mail server.

Comment: You are correct, Now I am getting an error "The Transport Failed to connect", Could you help out in that?

Answer (score -1):

Your code hides errors. err default property is number. So You say if err.number = 0 (same as false) then error, if err.number not 0 (ie error) everything fine.

Comment: Wrong. The condition `If Err Then` is correctly triggered when an error occurred, i.e. when the `Err` object is populated.